# Same html header in multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook-login

I have a website that has fb login in it. When the login is successful then the user info is added to the header. 
But how would I maintain this information when the user is moving from one webpage to another?

Answer (score 1):

### Welcome to StackOverflow!

Since PHP is tagged, i believe that you would be using PHP.

create a `header.php` or whatever you want to name file which has the header information.

and `include('header.php')` where ever it is required.

Doing this you will not have to repeat the code and maintain the same header

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) or [PHP Sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/de/features.sessions.php) for that.

The Cookie will be saved on the Client from your User, so only javascript can work with it. But Users could disable Cookies or/and Javascript, so this is a "unsafe" option.

I'd rather do this with Sessions, these will be handled from the server where the php runs. You need to send the user data from the login to a php file with saves it in a session. Then you could render another HTML file and fill it with the data from the Session.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need session.

Initialize session at the time of when use login

Example:

```
<?php
session_start();//required with session
if (!isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
  //welcome user
} else {
  //Register or login
}
?>
```

Details of [Session Use](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)

If you want to use same code for every page make individual file like `header.php`

and simply include this any where you want

```
include "header.php";
```

Details: [Include PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)